# Restore Wallet From Jaxx to Coinomi: ETH missing (but BTC and LTC are fine)

Tags: wallet-recovery, ethereum, coinomi

I have some BTC, ETH and LTC in a wallet created with Jaxx, but I want to use Coinomi instead. I downloaded Coinomi and chose Restore Wallet and entered my 12 words. My BTC and my LTC popped right up, but the ETH is nowhere to be seen (even after several hours).

I've tried adding some additional ETH wallets as suggested in this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/COINOMI/comments/7b8wxb/help_lost_ltc_when_restoring_my_old_wallet/

I can still access all currencies in my Jaxx wallet, so I could just transfer the ETH to my wallet in Coinomi, but I'd quite like to keep my transaction history.

Should my ETH be showing in Coinomi? Or am I wrong in my assumption that I can use my 12 words to restore in another wallet?

Answer (score 4):

Jaxx uses a different derivation path than Coinomi when handling ETH. Coinomi opted for the path as described in the ETH specification. Ledger has the same scheme as Coinomi.

Jaxx: M/44H/60H/0H/0
Coinomi: M/44H/60H/0H

You will have to do the following:

1. Delete any existing ETH wallets you have added by long pressing them (2 sec) in the Overview tab and clicking on the trash icon that appears.
2. Add another ETH wallet, but before clicking ADD, click on the gears icon next to the coin name in the coin list and then click on "ADVANCED SETTINGS" link on that popup, and enter this entire text in: M/44H/60H/0H/0 Then click add.

You should now see your ETH balance in Coinomi.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation path that worked for me when importing an ETH Jaxx wallet to Coinomi was M/44H/60H/0H/0 instead of M/44/60H/0H/0.